I used STRING_AGG to solve a problem in POSTGRES SQL
Unable to get the desired result after running a sql query.
I am working on SQL questions as a student. I had to solve a question which was
"For composers appearing in classical playlists,  create a comma separated list of the corresponding (distinct) playlist names."
Expected column names: composer, list_of_playlists
I used STRING_AGG() to solve the problem in POSTGRES SQL.
SELECT
t.composer,
STRING_AGG(p.name, ', ' ORDER BY p.playlist_id) AS list_of_playlists
FROM playlist_track AS pt
JOIN track AS t
ON pt.track_id = t.track_id
JOIN playlist AS p
ON pt.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
WHERE p.name LIKE '%Classical%' AND t.composer IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.composer

The resulted outcome after running the SQL query is as followed:
| composer           | list_of_playlists                       |
|                    |                                         |
| Aaron Copland      | Classical, Classical 101 - The Basics   |
| Anonymous          | Classical, Classical 101 - The Basics   |
| Antonio Vivaldi    | Classical, Classical 101 - The Basic    |
| Astor Piazzola     | Classical, Classical 101 - Deep Cuts    |
| Bela Bartok        | Classical, Classical 101 - Deep Cuts    |

BELOW IS THE SMALL SAMPLE OF THE TABLE CONSISTING OF COMPOSER, PLAYLIST_ID and NAME
COMPOSER       Playlist_id      Name

Aaron Copland     12           Classical
Aaron Copland     15           Classical 101 - The Basics
Anonymous     12           Classical
Anonymous     15           Classical 101 - The Basics
Antonio Vivaldi   15           Classical 101 - The Basics
Antonio Vivaldi   12           Classical
Astor Piazzolla   13           Classical 101 - Deep Cuts
Astor Piazzolla   12           Classical
Béla Bartók   13           Classical 101 - Deep Cuts
Béla Bartók   12           Classical

WHAT CHANGES SHOULD I MAKE IN MY SQL QUERY SO THAT THE RESULTED OUTCOME IS AS FOLLOWED:
| composer           | list_of_playlists                       |
|                    |                                         |
| Aaron Copland      | Classical, Classical 101 - The Basics   |
| Anonymous          | Classical, Classical 101 - The Basics   |
| Antonio Vivaldi    | Classical 101 - The Basic, Classical    |
| Astor Piazzola     | Classical 101 - Deep Cuts, Classical    |
| Bela Bartok        | Classical 101 - Deep Cuts, Classical    |


Remove the ORDER BY p.playlist_id in the string_agg

@VvdL, removing ORDER BY p.playlist_id might result in the desired output; however, the exact output will be indeterminate based on just the query as the order of the returned items in STRING_AGG will be dependent the order in which they are retreived from the table. Updating rows, even if the actual content doesn't change, can cause the retrieval order to change. The only way to guarantee a specific order is with ORDER BY. From the data in the original post, there isn't any practical ordering criiteria that will guarantee the desired output.

Can you describe the ordering in the desired outcome? Does the order matter?

It worked after removing order by, thanks

@AdityaMishra, although removing ORDER BY may have produced the desired output, that doesn't mean it will always produce the output in the desired order. If updates are applied to some rows of the tables such that the arrangement in storage is altered (even if the content of the updated rows isn't changed), list_of_playlists has a significant probability of appearing in a different order. Even running VACUUM FULL on those tables might result in a different order.

For the data presented, there aren't any practical changes that can be made to the query to guarantee the desired list order because there isn't a suitable attribute to sort on. Removing ORDER BY from STRING_AGG, as suggested in one of the comments, will result in a list with an order determined by the arrangement of the rows within table storage, which isn't something that can be directly controlled (neither playlist_id nor name produce the desired order). To demonstrate the dependence on retrieval order when ORDER BY isn't used, create a table and insert two values:
CREATE TABLE order_test (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  description TEXT
);

INSERT INTO
  order_test (description)
VALUES
  ('first item'),
  ('second item');

Running
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(description, ', ')
FROM
  order_test;

returns
|list|
|-|
|first item, second item|
After this update
UPDATE order_test
SET
  description = description
WHERE
  description = 'first item';

running the SELECT query returns
|list|
|-|
|second item, first item|

It worked after removing order by, thanks
